Are the models of PA recursively enumerable?
Is there a Turing machine (TM from now on) which lists every model of PA (without the induction axiom schema, so just addition and multiplication)? More specifically, can such a TM list all infinite models, representing each as an infinitely long list of objects, which are themselves finitely long lists of predicates and references to other objects?
I think it cannot, because of the following argument. Assume such a TM exists. Simulate this TM within another TM, TM2. which takes any FOL statement as input. Because TM2 lists every possible model, it can search for two models such that the input is true for one and false for the other. If it finds two such models, it will halt and output "not provable from PA." Now TM2 also (at the same time) enumerates every valid FOL proof from PA (with every induction axiom) and checks if it either proves or disproves the statement. If it does, it will halt, and output "provable from PA." This implies that PA is decidable, which is false.
Is my argument correct?

PA without the induction axiom schema is called Robinson arithmetic ($\mathsf{Q}$). See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic

What does it even mean to list models of PA? How do you encode a model as a string?

Hi, welcome to MSE. Further to Mark's comment.. A TM cannot possibly list every model of PA/Q however you slice it, because there are uncountably many models and models can be uncountably large. Even worse, every countable nonstandard model of PA is non-computable. So maybe a reasonable question to ask is: "are the computable models of Q recursively enumerable"?

Thanks for replying, Izaak! What does it mean for a model to be non-computable?

Mark, I figured that a model can be encoded something like this: use a symbol like '#' to denote a discrete object within the model. Following the # would be all the predicates of the object, like "zero." It can also have predicates like "successor" or "IsTheSumOf" which take references to another object, like a pointer, which can be done on a TM. So it's kind of like a bunch of C++ classes called 'Object' which each represent the objects in the model. If that makes any sense...

By computable I mean in the sense that Tennenbaum's theorem talks about. With your idea to have a TM print an infinite description of a model: if $M$ is a non-computable model then there can be no TM that prints a sensible infinite description of $M$, as that would enable one to compute the operations on $M$.
